# Streamlit fixed text search box and a clickable button at the bottom of streamlit app

Tags: python, html, css, streamlit

I'm trying hard to fix both a text search box and a voice search button at the bottom of the streamlit app UI but only textbox is getting fixed at the bottom. Button is not getting fixed but instead getting scrolled as I scroll the page. I tried many combinations in python, below is one straightforward approach

```
    text_col, button_col = st.columns([4, 1])
    
    # Define styling for both elements
    style = """
    <style>
      #stButtonVoice {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: 1rem;
      }
      
      .stTextInput {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin-right: 1rem;
      }
    </style>
    """
    
    # Inject the styling code for both elements
    st.markdown(style, unsafe_allow_html=True)
    
    # Add your text input and button
    with text_col:
        text_input = st.text_input(
            "Any further query?", placeholder="search here...", key="text_input")
    
    with button_col:
        voice_search_button = st.button("Voice Search", key="stButtonVoice")
```

Here is how the output is looking like

[image]

Appreciate any work around for this problem. Note that i want voice search bottom too aligned along the line of the search text box

Answer (score 1):

Because you are dealing with individual divs instead of finding the right class in the parent div. Replace your style with the following:

```py
style = """
   <style>
    .css-ocqkz7 {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 50%;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: end;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
       }
   </style>
   """
```

This will set the parent div to center, at the bottom of the screen. You can modify the css rules to your liking.

[image]